# Clauses in ecase macro take on package prefix

Tags: common-lisp, package, practical-common-lisp

I am trying to work through Practical Common Lisp.  I'm a lisp beginner.

I've defined a package using "quicklisp"  I load the package with (ql:quickload :spam filter)

One of the functions in this package looks like this:

```
    (defun increment-count (feature type)
     (ecase type
      (ham (incf (ham-count feature)))
      (spam (incf (spam-count feature)))))
```

When I try to call a function that calls this function in slime the case statement fails.  I think it fails because the compiler has added the package name as a prefix to the clauses.

Here is the error I'm seeing:

> HAM fell through ECASE expression. Wanted one of (HAM SPAM).
>     [Condition of type SB-KERNEL:CASE-FAILURE]
>
> Restarts:
>   0: [RETRY] Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request.
>   1: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
>   2: [ABORT] Abort thread (#)
>
> Backtrace:
>    0: (SB-KERNEL:CASE-FAILURE ECASE HAM (SPAMFILTER::HAM SPAMFILTER::SPAM))
>    1: (SPAMFILTER:INCREMENT-COUNT # HAM)
>    2: (SPAMFILTER:TRAIN "From exmh-users-admin@redhat.com  Mon Sep 23 12:06:27 2002 ..)
>    3: (SPAMFILTER::TRAIN-FROM-CORPUS #>((#P"/Users/jh/src/lisp/spamfilter/mail/easy_ham/1205.f9d66868c52039f7a147d9e2b4b05e1f" HAM) (#P"/Users/jh/src/lisp/spamfilter/mail/easy_ham/0090.314ec4268af7a3a1974d5e..
>    4: (SPAMFILTER:TEST-CLASSIFIER #((#P"/Users/jh/src/lisp/spamfilter/mail/easy_ham/0001.ea7e79d3153e7469e7a9c3e0af6a357e" HAM) (#P"/Users/jh/src/lisp/spamfilter/mail/easy_ham/0002.b3120c4bcbf3101e661161ee7..
>    5: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (SPAMFILTER:TEST-CLASSIFIER SPAMFILTER:*CORPUS* 0.1) #)
>    6: (EVAL (SPAMFILTER:TEST-CLASSIFIER SPAMFILTER:*CORPUS* 0.1))
>   --more--

I'm basing my conjecture that the compiler has added the prefix on Backtrace 0:

> 0: (SB-KERNEL:CASE-FAILURE ECASE HAM (SPAMFILTER::HAM SPAMFILTER::SPAM))

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks.

Comment: The ecase form is checking the key to see whether it's a one of two particular symbols.  I expect that you wrote the code in a file starting with something like `(in-package spamfilter)` and are now running some tests "from" another package, and aren't passing the symbol that you think you are.  The compiler's not *adding* anything.  The reader is reading a symbol, and interning it in a different package.  E.g., `(eq 'spamfilter:ham 'cl-user:spamfilter) => NIL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This REPL transcript may be instructive.  This doesn't have anything to do with the compiler *adding* anything, but that symbols in different packages aren't necessarily the same.

First, define a package and some a function using symbols in the *spam-filter* package:

```
CL-USER> (defpackage #:spam-filter
           (:use "COMMON-LISP"))
#<PACKAGE "SPAM-FILTER">
CL-USER> (in-package #:spam-filter)
#<PACKAGE "SPAM-FILTER">
SPAM-FILTER> (defun test (x)
               (ecase x
                 (ham "ham")
                 (spam "spam")))
TEST
```

Let's check that it works:

```
SPAM-FILTER> (test 'spam)
"spam"
```

OK, now let's go back to CL-USER:

```
SPAM-FILTER> (in-package "CL-USER")
#<PACKAGE "COMMON-LISP-USER">
```

Now let's try to call *spam-filter::test*:

```
CL-USER> (spam-filter::test 'spam)
; Evaluation aborted on #<SB-KERNEL:CASE-FAILURE expected-type:
                         (MEMBER SPAM-FILTER::HAM SPAM-FILTER::SPAM)
                         datum: SPAM>.
```

We get an error because the current package is CL-USER, so the reader reads the characters `spam` and interns "SPAM" to get the symbol *cl-user::spam*, which is *not* the same as *spam-filter::spam*.  Let's try calling it with *spam-filter::spam*:

```
CL-USER> (spam-filter::test 'spam-filter::spam)
"spam"
```

And surely enough, it still works.  For more about what's going on here, you might enjoy Ron Garret's [*The Complete Idiot’s Guide to Common Lisp Packages*](http://www.flownet.com/gat/packages.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Ways to solve trying to compare symbols from different packages:

- Usually it makes sense to make sure the symbols are in the right package. Normalize them into one package.
- use keyword symbols
- only compare the symbol names, but then you need to use something else than `ECASE`.
- use strings, but then you need to use something else than `ECASE`.

Comment: Regarding "something else than `ecase`": Alexandria has `switch`, `cswitch`, `eswitch`, which may be useful.